# How to solve encoding problems when sending email via Python 2.7?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, email, encoding

I have the following code in my Python 2.7, as the backend of my Contact form in my website:

```
import sys
import smtplib
from django.http import HttpResponse


form = request.POST



from_addr = form['name']+' <'+form['email']+'>'
to_addrs = ['myemail@address']
msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: Email sent from my website form\r\n\r\n"
   % (from_addr, ", ".join(to_addrs)))


msg = msg + form['message']


try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.address')
    s.starttls()
    s.login('myemail@address', 'mypassword')
    s.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg.encode('utf-8'))
    s.quit()

except smtplib.SMTPException:
    return HttpResponse(status=404)

return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

This code works, BUT... if I send a message like "¿En qué año estamos?" it arrives to my inbox as "En qu ao estamos?" (it deletes some characters). How can I solve this?